# tSQLt ExpectException Not Detecting exception

Tags: unit-testing, tsqlt

I was working on building a test to utilize the ExpectException for a error raised during execution of a stored proc, but the test were never passing as I expected them to.  So as part of my troubleshooting I made a very simple stored proc:

```
ALTER PROC testerror AS RAISERROR ('SomeError',16,1);
```

Then I built a test for this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [uspTest].[test the test]
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC testerror

    --Assert
    EXEC tSQLt.ExpectException @ExpectedMessagePattern = '%SomeError%',
                           @ExpectedSeverity = 16,
                           @ExpectedState = 1;

END;
```

When I run this in tSQLt the test fails with the following output:

```
Test Procedure: [SSISAdmin].[uspTest].[test the test] on SF5I-ETLTST01
[uspTest].[test the test] failed: (Error) 
SomeError[16,1]{testerror,1}
```

I have also tried passing NULL for the Severity and State based on examples that were in the documentation for the ExpectException as below but it still fails the test:

```
    EXEC tSQLt.ExpectException @ExpectedMessagePattern = '%SomeError%',
                           @ExpectedSeverity = NULL,
                           @ExpectedState = NULL;
```

I am guessing I am doing something wrong, but I am not sure what since this seems like a very simplified test and error message that is being returned.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

After doing some more extensive Googling I found some other examples and then saw that I had written my test wrong.  I had treated the ExpectException as an assertion where you execute the stored proc and then assert the results, but with the ExpectException you have to call the ExpectException method first and then execute the stored procedure that generates the error message.  To further explain this here is how the test looks when it works as expected:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE uspTest.[test the test]
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC tSQLt.ExpectException @ExpectedMessagePattern = '%SomeError%',
                               @ExpectedSeverity = NULL,
                               @ExpectedState = NULL;
    EXEC dbo.testerror;
END;
```